# How to refer to a public method of a java Activity class from the Kotlin companion object?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a mix of Kotlin and Java code in my Android App. I need to refer to a public void method declared in an Activity having java code from a Kotlin companion object. I tried some ways including making the method static but of no use.

```
// java code
public class SampleActivity extends Activity{

     public void toggleMark(boolean canTic)
     { // some code }

}

//Kotlin code
class MyUtils {

    companion object {

         fun setTicPref(context: Context)
         {
             // some code 
             (context as SampleActivity).toggleMark(true) // cannot find declaration to go to

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is your parameter Context when you need it to be SampleActivity? This should work so I think you’re missing some detail in the code you’ve shown besides forgetting the `public` keyword in the class declaration before.

Answer (score 2):

Make `SampleActivity` public.

change

```
class SampleActivity extends Activity{

     public void toggleMark(boolean canTic)
     { // some code }

}
```

to

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity{

     public void toggleMark(boolean canTic)
     { // some code }

}
```

Comment: It is already public, Activities are public by default.

Comment: @RKB "Activities are public by default" - that's for kotlin,   In java if there is no access specifier then it's [defined as default](https://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers)

Comment: @Nitish, as I mentioned, it is already public. I have edited the code in the question. When you create an Activity in Android Studio, it by default has a public access. you can verify the same.

Comment: @RKB So your problem have solved by adding the `public`, right?

Comment: No. please see my comment carefully.

Comment: @RK8, they were talking about default behavior of the compiler interpreting your code. We couldn't have known you used the IDE activity template and then removed the word `public` when you copied it here.

Comment: @RKB "Activities are public by default" - that's for kotlin, not for java. It can't refer the method before you add `public`. What is your problem?